# Is it possible to display virtual clock on screen?

Tags: software-recommendation, clock, widgets

Is there any clock widget available? In Windows, I can show a clock on my screen.

Please suggest any widget/package/software that can do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "in windows"? If you mean the Operating System you sure are off-topic here. On KDE there are plenty of widgets, including clocks. If you are on unity you can try this https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/up-clock/

Comment: in windows OS there is external widget we add and we can show round clock on screen so is there any widget or bundle for Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is actually dead now.  The link in the answer takes you over to the [Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/) https://snapcraft.io page, and you can see if there is a clock there that you like, or look into using [Conky](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-system-monitoring-with-conky-widgets).

Or you can try:
[Any package for clock widget in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497830/any-package-for-clock-widget-in-ubuntu)

---

You can try MacSlow's Cairo-Clock.  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/cairo-clock/

[image]

To install it, run the following from a command line:

```
sudo apt install cairo-clock
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah clock shows me.. but now seen like in picture you shows above.. is it shows like above picture ?

Comment: @HinaVaja It is configurable by right-clicking it and selecting properties.  You can choose several different faces for it.

Comment: yh i done it :)

Comment: This really worked

Comment: unable to locate package cairo-clock

Comment: @garg10may Updated answer.  That clock is long since gone, and I think it hasn't been around since Ubuntu 16.04.