# Any package for clock widget in Ubuntu

Tags: widgets

I want an analog clock widget to be displayed on my home screen in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Is there any package which I can install to for this?.
I checked on the google didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a GNOME Shell extension called `Desktop Clock` available which adds a clock to the desktop.

Simply click on the `OFF` icon to turn it on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want an application, there are multiple analog clocks, including the original xclock, oclock, swisswatch, and a few others.

If you want an actual widget to go in the top panel, you probably are looking for a gnome-shell extension.   Sadly, a brief search of gnome-shell extensions did not turn up any analog clocks.