# Display clock overlay over Desktop

Tags: desktop-background

I want to display the current time in big letters on my desktop, on top of my background picture. I don't have any icons on my desktop, so no need to worry about this. I found this old thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260202 that kind of works, however this displays it on top of whichever application I'm running, which I don't want. Is there a tool/way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any package for clock widget in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497830/any-package-for-clock-widget-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Not really, as this shows an analog clock. I just want it to say the time in numbers, e.g. if it's 3 seconds past 12:14 PM it should say "12:14:03 PM"

Comment: Yeah, Conky does this and you can configure it to show a whole lot of other stuff along with the time, it's extremely configurable but it's been a really long time since I've worked with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not really, as this shows an analog clock.

There have been some modifications to the app.

I installed the Desktop Clock widget as outlined in [this accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497830/any-package-for-clock-widget-in-ubuntu) in my 22.04 instance and it does indeed place an analogue clock on the desktop including seconds.

[image]

Note that my settings are for 24 hour format under `Date & Time`. `Formats` under `Language and Region` are set as France (hence the date text in French).

The gitlab description from the author is [available here](https://gitlab.com/AndrewZaech/azclock)

[image]

The widget is configurable by clicking on the tools icon after the app is installed by selecting `Open GNOME Shell extensions website` which will provide additional options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The wallpaper switcher application `variety` provides this functionality.  To enable it, start variety, go to Preferences, and select the Clock tab.

Here's an example.

[image]